# Where does maven package the XSD files?

Tags: xml, maven, jakarta-ee, xsd-validation, xml-validation

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http:/`enter code here`/maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
```

Aboave mentioned are the few lines from my POM.xml. Schema location is pointing to Maven repository. From where does maven gets these XSD files to validate the XML. Does it invokes the http URL ? If yes in that case it should not work when internet conenction is not available.

I understand that in spring framework these XSDs are packaged in JAR file thinking on the same i performed search on all the maven JARs but i could not find any XSD files.

Can someone help me with the location of these JARS. how the POM.XML gets validated and from where does it locate the XSD ?

Answer (score 0):

Xsd remains in maven jars only.

C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven.jar!\schemas\maven-4.0.0.xsd

C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven.jar!\schemas\maven-4.0.0.xsd

Comment: Thanks for responding quickly. i could not find it in the maven distribution. would you mind giving me some details if it exist in your maven provided libs.

Comment: As I gave the path, It is not in maven distribution. It is the part of maven plugin installed in your ide.

Comment: Thanks a lot  but the POM can be executed without the IDE, more interested on how it works when internet connection is not available without XSD available in distribution.